# System Settings won't start, Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04

Peace of You
try this commend but problem not solved

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: What happen if you run `gnome-control-center --verbose` on a terminal? You may edit your question with the output of `inxi -SG -! 31 -y 80`

Comment: What error messages does it give when run from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

this is happen when run gnome-control-center --verbose

```
mohamedramadan@mohamed-ramadan:~$ gnome-control-center --verbose
** (gnome-control-center:2740): DEBUG: 07:23:36.423: Enabling debugging (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.567: ActUserManager: calling 'ListCachedUsers' (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.567: Failed to identify the current session: No data available (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.567: ActUserManager: seat unloaded, so trying to set loaded property (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.567: ActUserManager: Listing cached users, so not setting loaded property (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.567: ActUserManager: Listing cached users, so not setting loaded property (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.568: ActUserManager: ListCachedUsers finished, will set loaded property after list is fully loaded (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.568: ActUserManager: tracking new user with object path /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.573: ActUserManager: unrefing manager owned by finished ListCachedUsers call (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: user mohamedramadan is now loaded (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: user mohamedramadan was not yet known, adding it (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: tracking user 'mohamedramadan' (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: not yet loaded, so not emitting user-added signal (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: no pending users, trying to set loaded property (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: ActUserManager: Seat wouldn't load, so giving up on it and setting loaded property (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: Got 1 users

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: adding user MohamedRamadan

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: user added: 1000 MohamedRamadan

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.574: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.585: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.586: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): GnomeDesktop-DEBUG: 07:23:36.619: Ignoring 'C.UTF-8' as a locale, since it lacks translations (gnome-control-center:2740): GnomeDesktop-DEBUG: 07:23:36.619: Ignoring 'C.UTF-8' as a locale, since it lacks translations (gnome-control-center:2740): GnomeDesktop-DEBUG: 07:23:36.620: Ignoring 'C.UTF-8' as a locale, since it lacks translations (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.623: ActUserManager: sending user-changed signal for user mohamedramadan (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: Got 1 users

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: adding user MohamedRamadan

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: user added: 1000 MohamedRamadan

(gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: 07:23:36.624: File does not exist (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.634: ActUserManager: sent user-changed signal for user mohamedramadan (gnome-control-center:2740): AccountsService-DEBUG: 07:23:36.634: ActUserManager: updating user mohamedramadan
```